# Buscar una columna de una tabla a través del nombre que hay en otra celda

Tags: excel

Estoy realizando un libro excel donde hay varias tablas relacionadas entre si, donde el número de filas y columnas puede variar.

Necesito introducir en una tabla una fórmula para que me de un valor en función de los valores de otra tabla, pero la columna que debe buscar cada vez es diferente en función del nombre que se da en otra celda.

Por ejemplo:

En la celda A2 escribo: `Quantity`

En la celda B2 necesitaría una fórmula que fuera:

```
=CONTAR.SI(Tabla1[Quantity];Tabla1[Quantity]<>0)
```

Pero si en la celda A2 escribo (por ejemplo) `description`, la formula se cambie a:

```
 =CONTAR.SI(Tabla1[description];Tabla1[desription]<>0)
```

Es posible hacer esto de alguna manera? Que en la llamada de la tabla, para la columna elija lo que se escribe en una celda?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Yo usaria vb, en el excel para eso no se si desde formulas se podria pero desde vb seguro

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con la función INDIRECTO para crear una referencia dinámica al rango:

> [Función
> INDIRECTO](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-indirecto-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fórmula usada es:

```
=CONTAR.SI(INDIRECTO("Tabla1[" & A2 & "]");"<>"&0)
```